# Freezing point lowering for a mixture of many liquids

Tags: physical-chemistry, solutions, temperature, colligative-properties

I have been taught that if I have a solute of molality $m$ mixed with a liquid, the freezing point in lowered by an amount $K_\mathrm{f}\cdot m$ where $K_\mathrm{f}$ is the molal freezing depression constant.

But if I have a solution containing three liquids, and if all the $K_\mathrm{f}$ values are known, what would be the lowering of freezing point of such a solution?

Comment: At some point one of the liquids will reach its own freezing point lowered by presence of two other liquids and whatever else you have there. Then it will freeze.

Comment: How do we calculate the freezing point?

Comment: Precisely as you described, via molality and Kf.

Comment: Molality is moles per kilogram of solvent right? If there are 3 liquid components do we take the one with highest contribution to the solution as the solvent?

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: Under the Calphad (Calculation of Phase Diagrams) framework, besides the binary terms representing the interactions of components A, B, and C (AB, BC, and AC), you may need a ternary term as well to represent ABC interactions in the Gibbs free energy.

Comment: @JonCuster So the conventional Kf*m  method would not hold ?

Comment: It is, not surprisingly, more complicated than that. The Kf*m model is an approximation to begin with, since it presume that Kf does not depend on concentration which is a poor approximation for many real liquids. But, an extension to a ternary would seem quite possible (and ternary interaction terms are not always needed). Depends on the liquids.

Comment: It seems suspicious.What is methanol molality in 1:1 molar mixture with water ? Or 1:1:1 methanol:water: acetonitrile ? Is methanol molality in the former the same or different to methanol molality in the latter ?

Comment: IMHO, molarity relates to total volume and molality to total mass.

Comment: Or to total mass of major solvent components. Wikipedia mentions "mixed solvent mass".